# Did a Father save his son after digging for 38 hours after the Armenian earthquake?

Tags: religion, natural-disasters

There's an inspirational story that is very popular on God based websites. Here is the version I am familiar with that was forwarded to me on Whatsapp many times before Yom Kippur:

> This story is true and appears in Chinuch in Turbulent Times by Rabbi Dov Brezak published by ArtScroll
>
> About 30 years ago, an earthquake in Armenia killed over 30,000 people
> in less than four minutes. One father raced to the elementary school
> his son attended only to discover that the building no longer existed;
> it was a heap of rubble. Recovering from his initial shock, he
> remembered the promise he made to his son: “No matter what, I’ll
> always be there for you.”
>
> Although the situation seemed hopeless, the distraught father was
> determined not to give up. What kept him going was his promise to his
> son.
>
> He mentally retraced the steps he took each morning when he brought
> his son to school and figured out where his son’s classroom was
> located under the rubble. Racing over to the spot of the no longer
> existing classroom, he began to dig through the rubble.
>
> Other well-meaning parents tried to pull him off the debris, saying,
> “It’s too late. There’s nothing you can do.” But he just kept digging,
> responding to the skeptics with one sentence, “Are you going to help
> me or not?” They did not help him, and so he continued on his own.
>
> Firefighters arrived at the scene of the tragedy and also tried to
> dissuade him. “We’ll take care of it. Go home.”
>
> The father remained undaunted and just asked, “Are you going to help
> me or not?” No help was forthcoming because the rescue teams felt they
> could better use their resources where there was still hope of saving
> lives. At this site, it didn’t look like there was anything they could
> do.
>
> The father proceeded on his own, committed to the promise he had made
> his son. “No matter what, I’ll always be there for you.”
>
> He dug for 12 hours, 24 hours — 36 hours. In the 38th hour, he pulled
> back a boulder and heard his son’s voice. He screamed his son’s name
> and heard a voice reply, “It’s me, Dad! I told the other kids not to
> worry. I told them that if you were alive, you would come to save me,
> because I knew you would keep your promise, ‘No matter what, I’ll
> always be there for you.’ You did it!”
>
> When the building collapsed, the beams fell in a triangular wedge that
> protected this boy and 13 of his classmates.
>
> This story is true. It is also a parable; a parable for Yom Kippur.

I've also seen this story on Christian websites as well such as here: [He has promised He will always be there for you](https://www.irontontribune.com/2021/05/16/he-has-promised-he-will-always-be-there-for-you/)

Is this story true?

Comment: The story comes from the 1998 book A Father Who keeps His Promises by Scott Hahn. You can read it his original presentation here:
https://www.scribd.com/book/626003398/A-Father-Who-Keeps-His-Promises-God-s-Covenant-Love-in-Scripture 
Hahn's story states it was 1989 but the earthquake hit Armenia in 1988. It's also really doubtful that parents would just give up on digging out a school because "their muscles began to ache" as he states.

Comment: @Legion600 that seems to be a decent answer. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's a good starting point to look for one.

Comment: The earthquake hit in December 1988 and people were still talking about it in January 1989. Perhaps that detail in Hahn's story is a minor detail the editors didn't catch.

Comment: Related story about 1988 Armenian earthquake survival hoaxes: https://www.rferl.org/a/fake-news-soviet-style-the-armenian-earthquake-rescue-that-was-too-good-to-be-true/29643951.html

Comment: Story about a boy with similar name (Arman vs. Armand) to the one in the Hahn book. Doesn't say anything about 38 hours and father rescuing, says he remembers townspeople helping. https://www.nydailynews.com/2007/05/10/1988-quake-victim-angel-are-reunited/

Comment: More about Arman Ghazaryan: https://www.americares.org/news/2007-0522-1988-armenia-earthquake-survivor-returns-for-americares-25th/